# passing facebook info between viewsController

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

i have been looking on the net to see whether i need to place the delegates in the profileViewController (which is the view the info is going to) or i need the delegates in the login/signup viewControllers i dont know how to pass the info profilePicture, name, login status please help,

EDIT::

i was able to pass the user.name through my protocols but i can not pass FBProfilePictureView

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>


@protocol passNames <NSObject>

- (void)setFBName: (NSString *)FBName;
- (void)setFBProfilePicture: (id<FBGraphUser>)FBPicture;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>


@property (weak) id <passNames> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *FBNamePass;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBProfilePictureView *FBProfilePicture;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NeXtViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;


@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize delegate, FBNamePass, FBProfilePicture;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



// Create a FBLoginView to log the user in with basic, email and likes permissions
// you should always ask for basic permissions when loggin the user in
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"email",@"user_likes"]];

// set this loginUIViewCOntroller to be the loginView button's delegate
loginView.delegate = self;


// align the button in the center horizontally
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(25, 299, 271, 50);

// add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:loginView];

//[self pushViewController];


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// this method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
//self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;


//    FBProfilePicture.profileID = user.id;
//    NSLog(@"%@ FB", FBProfilePicture.class);
//    FBNamePass = user.name;
//    NSLog(@"%@ user", FBNamePass);
[self pushViewController:user.name andProfilePicture:user];
}


- (BOOL)isUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)firstUser equalToUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)secondUser {
return
[firstUser.id isEqual:secondUser.id] &&
[firstUser.name isEqual:secondUser.name] &&
[firstUser.first_name isEqual:secondUser.first_name] &&
[firstUser.middle_name isEqual:secondUser.middle_name] &&
[firstUser.last_name isEqual:secondUser.last_name];
}



// implement the loginViewShowingLoggedInUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a logged-in user experoience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
self.statusLabel.text = @"Logged in";

if ([self.statusLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Logged in"]) {
    //NeXtViewController *n = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NeXt"];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:n animated:NO];

}
}

// implement the loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a logged-out user experoience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
self.nameLabel.text = @"";
self.statusLabel.text = @"You're not logged in";
}

// You need to override loginView:handleError in order to handle possible errors that can occur during login
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
{
NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

// If the user should perform an action outside of you app to recover,
// the SDK will provide a message for the user, you just need to surface it.
// This conveniently handles cases like Facebook password change or unverified Facebook accounts.
if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
    alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
    alertTitle = @"Facebook Error";

    // This code will handle session closures since that happen outside of the app.
    // You can take a look at our error handling guide to know more about it
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
} else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
    alertTitle = @"Session Error";
    alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

    // If the user has cancelled a login, we will do nothing.
    // You can also choose to show the user a message if cancelling login will result in
    // the user not being able to complete a task they had initiated in your app
    // (like accessing FB-stored information or posting to Facebook)
} else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
    NSLog(@"user cancelled login");

    // For simplicity, this sample handles other errors with a generic message
    // You can checkout our error handling guide for more detailed information
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
} else {
    alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
    alertMessage = @"Please try again later";
    NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@",error);
}

if (alertMessage) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                message:alertMessage
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}




}

- (void)pushViewController:(NSString *)user andProfilePicture:(id<FBGraphUser>)profilePicture
{
NeXtViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NeXt"];
[controller setFBNameString:user];
//controller.profilePicture = profilePicture;
[controller setFBProfilePicture:profilePicture];
NSLog(@"%@",profilePicture);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}

@end
```

NeXtViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface NeXtViewController : UIViewController <passNames>
{
ViewController *view;
}


@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *FBNameString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBProfilePictureView *profilePicture;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *FBProfilePictureView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;


- (IBAction)FBLogOut:(id)sender;

@end
```

NeXtViewController.m

```
#import "NeXtViewController.h"

@interface NeXtViewController ()

@end

@implementation NeXtViewController

@synthesize FBNameString = _FBNameString, profilePicture = _profilePicture;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

view = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[view setDelegate:self];
self.nameLabel.text = _FBNameString;
//self.FBProfilePictureView.profileID = _profilePicture.profileID;
NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.FBProfilePictureView.class, self.FBNameString.class);

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)setFBName:(NSString *)FBName
{
_FBNameString = FBName;
}

- (void)setFBProfilePicture:(id<FBGraphUser>)FBPicture
{
self.FBProfilePictureView.profileID = FBPicture.id;
}

- (IBAction)FBLogOut:(id)sender
{
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
if (FBSessionDidBecomeClosedActiveSessionNotification) {
    ViewController *views = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:views animated:NO];
    views.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
}


@end
```

Comment: Post some code, it'll help us to give exact idea.

Comment: Have you successfully obtaining the info? And put some code man.

Comment: i printed everything in the project

Answer (score 1):

You don't need delegates in my opinion (from what I gather from your question). What you can do, is get a reference to the 'profileViewController' from your 'login/signup viewControllers' and just pass some information to them. Let's take the assumption you're using the storyboard and segues. In your profileViewController.h you would create a few properties like so:

```
@interface profileViewController

@property(nonatomic) UIImage* profilePicture;
@property(nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property(nonatomic) NSString* loginStatus;

//all your methods and properties...

@end
```

Then in your login/signup view controllers, find a way to find the profileViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the profile view controller from segue and cast it
    profileViewController* profileVC = (profileViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];

    // Set the properties in the profile VC Class
    [profileVC setProfilePicture:myImage];
    [profileVC setName:myName];
    [profileVC setLoginStatus:myLoginStatus];
}
```

and then whenever the 'viewDidLoad' or 'init' is called in the profileViewController, the properties should be set and ready to use! It doesn't have to be a segue you are using, just any way of accessing the profileViewController before you use it.

Comment: im not using segues though yes im using UINavigationController but the two viewControllers are not connect by a segue and the UIImage is FBProfilePictureView

Comment: and the user.id which is what is used to give value to FBProfilePictureView is a string

Answer (score 0):

Tried to set your data into NSUserDefault it is easy to use and share data among multiple classes is simple using NSUserDefault.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Saving

```
 AppDelegate * degate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    delegate.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[delegate.prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[delegate.prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

[delegate.prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieving

```
delegate.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [delegate.prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [delegate.prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

And define your NSUSserDefault in your AppDelegate and share using AppDelageate object and and whatever your data among multiple classes.

Tried this one